# How to solve this first order linear ODE $ Y'(y)- \frac{n^2}{y}Y(y)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation as follows:

$$ Y'(y)- \frac{n^2}{y}Y(y)=0 , y>1 $$

I know that for linear differential equations of the form e.g.

$$ Y'(y)-2n^2Y(y)=0 $$

The solution is $e^{-2n^2y}$ (I'm also not completely sure on the motivation behind this) How should I approach the problem when I have the variable of the function Y(y) I'm trying to find multiplied in the equation.

Comment: It is separable, i.e. you can write it in the form $$\frac{Y'(y)}{Y(y)}=\frac{n^2}y$$ and now you can integrate both sides. Note that we may assume $Y(y)\neq0$ for all $y$ (otherwise we would know that $Y\equiv 0$ by the Picard-Lindelöf uniqueness Theorem for solutions to ODEs)

Comment: Your equation is still linear. It has just variable coefficients but it's linear. linear and separable.

Comment: I do not see how it is separable the form separable would mean there is another function involved of a different variable ? , please note to consider $n^2$ a constant, I have actually obtained this differential equation by trying to solve a heat equation.

Comment: @ilovemathexchange don't confuse separation of variables in ode and separation of variables in pde, they're completely different things

Answer (score 1):

$$Y'(y)- \frac{n^2}{y}Y(y)=0 , y>1$$
It's separable, linear of first order.
$$Y'(y)= \frac{n^2}{y}Y(y)$$
$$ \frac {Y'(y)}{ Y(y)}=\frac{n^2}{y}$$
$$ (\ln Y(y))'=\frac{n^2}{y}$$
Integrate
$$ \ln Y(y)=n^2\int \frac{dy}{y}$$
$$ \ln Y(y)=n^2\ln y +C$$
Take exponential on both sides:
$$ Y(y)=c_1y^{n^2 }$$

---

$$yY'(y)- {n^2}Y(y)=0$$
Your equation is linear and separable. And you can also consider it as an Euler-Cauchy differential equation. Plug $y^m$ and find the exponent m. Then the solution is:
$$Y(y)=cy^m$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the formula for solve the following ODE:

> Notice that I changed the letters!!

$$y'+P(x)y=Q(x) \,\,\,\, (1)$$

which is:

$$y = \frac{\int v(x)\cdot Q(x) dx+ C}{v(x)}\,\,\,\, (2)$$

where $v(x) = e^{\int P(x)dx}\,\,\,\, (3)$

This formula (2) is obtained when you multiply (1) and set the relation in (3). In this case the answer is:

$$y=Cx^{n^2}$$
or writing like you
$$Y(y)=Cy^{n^2}$$

Comment: Is P(x) required to be continuous? in this case it would not be since 1/y requires y not zero..

Comment: Yes. Both $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ must be continuous.

Comment: how do we know P(x) is continuous in this case?

Comment: isn't it the case that 1/y is not continuous since y cannot be zero

Comment: If you have the following function: $\frac{1}{input}$, and make $input > 0$ (in this case you had set $input$> 1), then it becomes continuous in its domain and you can take derivatives and evaluate them without worries.