# Exact solution and Euler method approximation for a first order differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, eulers-method

Having trouble wrapping my brain around this question.. don't know where to start.

> A. Consider the differential equation  $f'(x) = (x + 1)f(x)$ with $f(0) =1$. What is the exact formula for $f(x)$?

I tried solving for $f(x)$ but that just gives me $(x+1)f'(x)$. I feel like that's not sufficient here.

> B. Solve for $f(.2)$ using Eulers approximation method with increment $h = .01$ for $x\in[0,0.2]$.

Edit- my work for part A.

integral f'(x) = integral(x+1) *f(x)+(x+1) * integral (f(x)

so f(x) = ((x^2+x)/2)*f(x) + (x+1) * (f(x)^2)/2.

I don't believe this is the right answer.

Comment: If you dont show some work your question will be closed.

Comment: **Hint:** The ODE is a separable differential equation. You will also note that your expression for $f(x)$ is incorrect.

Comment: $$\frac {f'}{f}=(\ln f )' $$ Then integrate both sides

Comment: With Laplace Transform, it is very easy.

Comment: I have modified your previous title "Having trouble wrapping my brain...". I think you will agree with me...

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x) = (x + 1)f(x)$$
Is a separable differential equation of first order.

Rewrite as:
$$ \frac {df}{dx}=(x+1)f$$
$$ \frac {df}{f}=(x+1)dx$$
Integrate both sides and apply initial condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to this one: [How to solve this first order linear ODE $ Y'(y)- \frac{n^2}{y}Y(y)=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535981/how-to-solve-this-first-order-linear-ode-yy-fracn2yyy-0/3536051?noredirect=1#comment7281623_3536051)

This is just an additional information, since all the other answers are correct. The following is my answer to the question linked.

"You can also use the formula for solve the following ODE:

> Notice that I changed the letters!!

$$y'+P(x)y=Q(x) \,\,\,\, (1)$$

which is:

$$y = \frac{\int v(x)\cdot Q(x) dx+ C}{v(x)}\,\,\,\, (2)$$

where $v(x) = e^{\int P(x)dx}\,\,\,\, (3)$

This formula (2) is obtained when you multiply (1) by $v(x)$ and set the relation in (3)."